# Relative databinding from a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The data binding to the parent element's `DataContext` with `{Binding RelativeSource={...}` doesn't work for me in this case.
I played around with different inputs to `AncestorType` and `AncestorLevel` but it can't find no source to bind to...

Here is the XAML markup:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectGroups}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProjectGroup}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}">
                            <Label.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteText}" Command="{Binding DeleteGroup}"></MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Label.ContextMenu>
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

As you can see i'm trying to bind properties of the inner element `MenuItem` to the same `DataContext` as the outter `ListView` has.

what am i missing? why does this not work?

Comment: Elements ContextMenu, ToolTip, Popup - create their own little Window that is popuping over the main Window.
Think about how you can display the UI element differently without affecting the existing layout of the elements?
And since this is another Window, it has its own Visual Tree in which you cannot find the elements of the Main Window.
Therefore, bindings of the ElementName and AncestorType types to the elements of the main Window will not work.

Comment: The solution is in the comment to the answer to the duplicate question. I'll try to find a better duplicate though. Perhaps look through these search results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+ContextMenu+data+binding+placementtarget